# Removing an array result

Tags: php, arrays

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 29372
        [product_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1469
                        [type_id] => 1
                        [title] => Hearth 2 Hearth
                        [cover] => 21cf9d7d09d403251ba5d01ff33cd089.jpg
                        [coverid] => 1178
                        [inserted_by] => 0
                        [inserted_date] => 2011-02-11 13:55:23
                        [status_id] => 0
                    )

            )

        [variable_id] => 9
        [variable_value] => 2011-02-11
        [master_value] => 
        [released_date] => 2011-02-11
        [price] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 1469
                        [media_format] => VCD
                        [price] => 29000
                        [discount] => 5
                    )

            )

        [media_format] => VCD
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 30074
        [product_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1470
                        [type_id] => 1
                        [title] => Hearth 2 Hearth
                        [cover] => 149ddd4d1d5e567c1300d4831323e1c5.jpg
                        [coverid] => 1177
                        [inserted_by] => 6
                        [inserted_date] => 2011-02-16 15:18:58
                        [status_id] => 0
                    )

            )

        [variable_id] => 9
        [variable_value] => 2011-02-11
        [master_value] => 
        [released_date] => 2011-02-11
        [price] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 1470
                        [media_format] => DVD
                        [price] => 39000
                        [discount] => 0
                    )

            )

        [media_format] => DVD
    )
```

I want the result by media_format = DVD so the whole array is gone, is there anyway to delete an array or remove it?

Comment: Yes just make it empty, nothing, Null

Answer (score 4):

The same way you "delete" any variable:

```
unset($array[$index]);
```

Comment: I dont know how to use this... can you be more specific? like don't you need to arrange it or something... like i want only this group of array = [media_format] => DVD

Comment: @mad Sorry, I don't quite understand your question/problem. Can you update your question with example output you expect?